# Is the output complete after omitting [TCP segment of reassembled PDU]?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

If the `tshark -r dumpfile` output contains the type *[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]*, as in

> 81 3.164109000 4.5.6.7 -> 12.13.14.15 TLSv1.2 609 Application
>   Data
>
> 83 3.164523000 4.5.6.7 -> 12.13.14.15 TCP 2802 [TCP segment of
>   a reassembled PDU]
>
> 85 3.277723000 4.5.6.7 -> 12.13.14.15 TLSv1.2 4170 Application
>   Data

[it](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200805/msg00206.html) [is](https://serverfault.com/questions/516401/why-does-wireshark-think-this-frame-is-a-tcp-segment-of-a-reassembled-pdu) [clear](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200806/msg00047.html) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836944/how-wireshark-marks-some-packets-as-tcp-segment-of-a-reassembled-pdu) [this](https://superuser.com/questions/255157/tcp-segment-of-a-reassembled-pdu) [means](http://fixunix.com/tcp-ip/66988-tcp-segment-reassembled-pdu-errors.html) several TCP segments containing an application-level PDU (in this case, TLSv1.2).

If it is omitted from the output (via further processing, f.ex. `grep`), does the trace still *contain all the information about the flows*, or not?

In other words, can one see from the remaining lines (here lines 81 and 85), how much data flowed from whom to whom? ([Question also on ask.wireshark.com](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/46802/is-the-output-complete-after-omitting-tcp-segment-of-reassembled-pdu))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [answered at the Wireshark forum](https://ask.wireshark.org/answer_link/46804/):

> you can't omit those frames, because they are part of the TCP/TLS conversation.